# Letting Ubuntu boot even with a failed harddisk

Tags: boot, server, mount, hard-drive

I have a server in a remote location.
The server has multiple harddisks attached to it.

How can I let it boot even with a failed (or fsck failed) harddrive?

- It will boot with uncommented fstab entry.
- I have set the flag `nofail`.
- I would expect the system to run without that drive mounted (as long as it is not the system disk)
- The drives are not in raid. Just plain drive - mountpoint

It would make remote trouble shooting a lot easier because I run desktop hardware without remote management.

My current FSTAB sample entry (not primary system disk):

```
# <file system>              <mount point>    <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/{asdf-...} /mnt/disk2       ext4    defaults,nofail 0       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ext filesystem, the filesystem parameter `errors=continue` might help you.

However, I'd look into the underlying cause and try to mitigate that with RAID if the load is important.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So `<options>` would be `defaults,nofail,errors=continue` in fstab?

Comment: Is it physical or virtual server?

Comment: hello netbat,

the server is physical, the Disks are not connected in raid mode. They are connected as individual disks.

Comment: @JulianBechtold Yes, nofail should continue the boot instead of systemd dropping to emergency shell, errors=continue make it stay active even when there's errors. The other options are to panic the system and remount it as read-only, which depending on the case, might put the system in a state where it can't be remotely accessed any more.